# Memory leak issues while using Runtime.getRuntime().exec in Java to execute commands in Linux environment

Tags: java, linux, apache

I am using the following code to run Linux commands from Java, but I am getting memory leak error. PFA error and code. kindly, suggest me some solutions if you have faced this already.

```
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:448)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:345)
        at com.comcast.xarc.services.XarcHomeService.executeCommandLine(XarcHomeService.java:160)
        at com.comcast.xarc.struts.action.XarcHomeAction.execute(XarcHomeAction.java:1095)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:421)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:226)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:415)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1023)
        ... 27 more
May 05, 2015 3:17:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 05, 2015 3:17:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 05, 2015 3:17:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
log4j: setFile called: C:/2015-05-05/2015-05-05.log, false
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: setFile called: C:/2015-05-05/2015-05-05.log, false
log4j: setFile ended
May 05, 2015 3:17:14 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation.
May 05, 2015 3:17:14 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

---

```
 try {

    // run the Unix "ps -ef" command
        // using the Runtime exec method:
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd run;./run.sh");

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
             InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
             InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

        // read the output from the command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        // read any errors from the attempted command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("exception happened - here's what I know: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

Comment: pls update your full class code and exception stack trace..

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your problem is

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1023)
```

The problem is due to the script command that you are trying to run and it is looking for into an invalid directory and you get the `IOException` No such file or directory exists. Make sure you give the correct path and try starting your apache again

Comment: The "No such file or directory exists" error is due to wrong folder. i am getting the memory leak problem even when the commands are executed successfuly. the problem is with runtime.exec. it would be  great if you could suggest some alternative for this.

Comment: how many instances of apache you are running? and are the ports apache using is already shared with some other process..? running multiple apache instances leads to the problem..and specify your system memory and amount of memory consumed by apache process

Comment: do you have any idea on how to check the number of instances of apache?

Comment: @sathurya By instances i mean the number of 'apache programs' you have installed in your system..if you have started more than one apache at a time it will cause the memory leak problem..since running one instances of apache will consume more memory(RAM) and what port do you use for apache..check if that port is shared with some other application..